# Hedera Mirror Node - Filter configuration for multiple accounts

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I am trying to setup a mirror node ([hedera-mirror-node](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-mirror-node)) and specifically set some filters for a few accounts I want to track.

I am trying to restrict the mirror node to only include a specific set of accounts `[accountA, accountB, accountC]` and all their activity.

I checked some of the documentation but I can't seem to get it to work, would anyone have pointers on how to configure it to do this if it's at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you can configure the mirror node filter in `application.yaml` https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-mirror-node/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#filtering-example

So I guess you have to exclude all accounts and include only account A,B,C.

The following configure should work but I have not tried it.

```
hedera:
  mirror:
    importer:
      parser:
        exclude:
          - entity: *
        include:
          - entity: [0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3]
```